# PHP GET data issue

Tags: php, url, get

I have an issue in posting php data.
I have small website and I made a php file cat.php.
Normally to post id it should be like that `cat.php?id=.`
I'm asking if I can do it like this `cat-ID.php.`

Comment: If you mean `cat-<ID>.php` yes with some url rewriting your could. But I think something like /cat/<ID>/ is would be nicer.

Comment: But cat.php is a dynamique file ! thats mean i have just one cat.php but the content change depending on the ID posted ! So the file get the infomations related to that id from the mysql database !

Comment: but if the visitor goes on this user www.example.com/cat-1.php the hosting do not have a file with that name ! can you understand what i mean !

Comment: The url could be rewritten behind the scenes to `cat.php?id=<ID>`. You will have to read up a bit on url rewriting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your first example is `POST`, not `GET` (e.g. `cat.php?id=5` would be `$_GET['id']`). You can, though, use htaccess rewrites to create URLs something like `cat-[id].html` instead, which is cleaner. See examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html

**Update:**

Mod Rewrite example. This would be in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule cat-([0-9]+)\.html cat.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Then in PHP, you could:

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

And you should be able to hit /cat-5.html and see 5 echoed.

Comment: Can you please help me to do this with this domain for example : http://www.google.com/cat-1.php how can i use htaccess to make it like  this http://www.google.com/cat.php?id=1

Comment: I dont want it in this way ! i want it like that cat-ID.php not /cat/ID

Comment: What you're asking for isn't exactly possible. You COULD do: cat-[ID] but not with .php on there. You're not creating different FILES, you're creating different REQUESTS.

Comment: Look ! The exact ting that i want is im creating script so normally so far i will add code to htacces to execute html as php so the result will be like this http://www.google.com/cat-1.html and the server will execute it as http://www.google.com/cat.php?id=1 .

Comment: Updated, should do what you want now (cat-5.html will parse to cat.php?id=5)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work for your scenario:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule cat-([0-9]+)\.php cat.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This would rewrite `/cat-3.php` to `cat.php?id=3` and `/cat-666.php` to `cat.php?id=666` and so on.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can turn cat-ID.html to be run as cat.php?id=

Comment: Just change the `RewriteRule` to `cat-([0-9]+)\.html cat.php?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: @checkopenport - no problemo=)

Comment: @checkopenport - why did you change the correct answer. If you look at my comment from above I was the only one that directly said that this could be done in the form `cat-<ID>.php` and also I didn't steal any answer, my regex was fine from the beginning which his wasn't.